# Multiple integral what am i doing wrong?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$ \iint _d (x-y)^2*{{{e^y}^+}^z} \qquad   d:x-y\ge -1,x-y\le1,x+y\ge1,x+y\le3  $$
i was trying to separate   it to two multiple integral integrals but i cant integrate this integral, i was trying to Integrate  by parts and replacing the variables like so $$ u=x+y \quad du=dx \quad $$ 
and then integrate by parts like so $$ f=u^2\quad df=fu \quad dg=e^u \quad g=e^2 $$
but it dosent work

thanks

Comment: One of the inequalities defining $d$ is repeated. Typo?

Comment: you are right i have corrected it

Comment: Is the power of e (y+z)?  It is not clear and has not come out properly in MathJax

Comment: yes its e to the power (x+y)

Comment: The first step is to figure out the region $d$. It looks like a rectangle to me. Then you have to decide whether to change variable to $x-y,x+y$ or whether to stick with $x,y$. Are you happy with Jacobians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more interesting to substitute your variables in a way such that the boundaries become simpler expressions. At first glance you notice that both the integral and the boundary expressions only contain terms of $x+y$ and $x-y$ so you might want to try the substitution: 
$$
x+y = u \\
x-y = v
$$
The boundary conditions then become:
$$
-1\le v \le 1 \\
1 \le u \le 3
$$
and by using the transformation formula for double integrals, the new integral becomes:
$$
\int_{-1}^1dv\int_1^3 v^2 e^u |\left| 
\begin{array}{c c}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}\right|| du =\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1dv\int_1^3 v^2 e^u du
$$

Comment: thanks man, its much easier with  Jacobians